# Assign Change-Event inside a RenderTreeBuilder

Tags: c#, blazor

i've got the following code:

```
@code
{
    RenderFragment CreateComponent() => builder => 
    {
        builder.OpenElement(0, "input");
        //...
        builder.AddAttribute(0, "onchange", EventCallback.Factory.Create(foo, DoSomething))
    }

    void DoSomething()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

I want to assign the onchange-event of a checkbox to a method, but when I do it like this I get the following error:

> Argument 2: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'EventCallback'

What I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

I changed now to:

```
builder.AddAttribute(1, "Change", RuntimeHelpers.TypeCheck<EventCallback<bool>>(EventCallback.Factory.Create(context, (args) => DoSomething(args))));
```

Now I receive multiple error's:

> A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property '.DoSomething(object)'

> Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type

**Update 2**

My RenderFragment-Method looks like this in the original:

```
RenderFragment<RadzenTreeItem> RenderFileOrFolder = (context) => builder =>
    
builder.OpenElement(0, "input");
//...
builder.AddAttribute(0, "onchange", EventCallback.Factory.Create(context, DoSomething))
```

So probably that's the Problem...

Comment: The first snippet looks Ok-ish but you shortened it. Post the actual code, exact error message an indicate which line that points to. What is `foo` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
builder.AddAttribute(12, "Click", Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.TypeCheck<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.MouseEventArgs>>(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback.Factory.Create<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.MouseEventArgs>(this, 
     (args) => Click(args, "Button with text")
  )));
```

Comment: that's also not working... Maybe you can have a look at my updated description

Comment: Check the type parameters. Mouseeventargs.